# Кнопка-переключатель

Tags: html, javascript

Как можно сделать кнопку, чтоб по клику она залипала/впадала, а по второму клику принимала первоначально значение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 картинки - `btn_on.jpg`, `btn_off.jpg`

JS:

```
function switchButton(name) {
  var bImg = document.getElementById(name+'_img');
  var bInput = document.getElementById(name+'_input');
  if (!bImg || !bInput) return false;
  bImg.src = (bInput.value) ? 'btn_off.jpg' : 'btn_on.jpg';
  bInput.value = (bInput.value) ? 0 : 1;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rememberme_input" name="rememberme" value="0" />
<img id="rememberme_img" onclick="switchButton('rememberme')" src="btn_off.jpg" /> Запомнить меня
```

Это полный комплект, можно заносить в форму(придет `$_POST['rememberme']`), замените только пути к картинкам. Ну и стили надо прописать, да)

*Удобнее всего это завернуть в php-функцию*

Answer (score 1):

```
$(selector).toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
});
//clicked - класс, показывающей кнопку нажатой
```